# In firebase how does the db.collection().where() does?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Talking about querying on Firestore, I found `collection().where()` function.

It would be a great help, if I could get some good information about the syntax of how does this `.where()` function works.

Found something like this in a tutorial.

```
const userExist = db.collection('data').where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
```

How does the code above work?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in your question will return all documents that exist in the `data` collection, where the array property called `users` contains an email that is equal with what `user.email` returns.